# Name Clash even though I'm not using both interfaces

Tags: java, spring, jpa, name-clash

I'm getting this annoying message :

> Error:(8, 8) java: name clash: save(java.lang.Iterable) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository and save(java.lang.Iterable) in org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

I'm not using `CrudRepository` in my code, so how come im getting this weird message? How can I fix it?

Comment: Provide the relevant code associated with this error message.

Comment: Yes you are. `JpaRepository` <- `PagingAndSortingRepository` <- `CrudRepository`. Error looks like you are mixing wrong versions of dependencies, i.e. an older version of Spring Data Common with Spring Data JPA or a wrong java version.

Comment: Thanks! it was a dependency issue, had a wrong Commons version, just had to change the gradle config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a dependency issue. The following dependency resolves the issue

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>**1.2.1.RELEASE**</version>
  </dependency>
```